# Python- If, and, and or - across rows and columns

Tags: python, if-statement

1. I am new to Pandas and am trying to recreate some excel sheets I have created as an introduction to pandas.
2. In excel I have the formula: `=IF(J99="","",IF(OR(AND(I98>J98,I99<J99),AND(I98<J98,I99>J99)),E99,""))`
3. I have currently created a MACD dataframe using:

```
    import pandas_ta as ta
    import yfinance as yf
    
    #Inputs
    
    ticker= "AAPL"
    time = '5y'
    Lower_MA= 12
    Upper_MA= 26
    Span = 9
    df2= yf.Ticker(ticker).history(period= time)[['Close','Open','Volume']]
    df2.ta.macd(close='Close', fast= Lower_MA,slow= Upper_MA, signal= Span, append=True)
```

4. I now want to do something similar to the excel formula where column I= MACDs, J=MACDh, and E is the date. Is this possible, or am I biting off more than I can chew too early.

Comment: you can do this, but remember that python (and pandas) does not work in the same way as excel...  for example this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270524/cannot-calculate-macd-via-python-pandas

Comment: @D.L I am sure I may be forcing this solution. Would you recommend I go about it another way?

Comment: I would take a similar method with `DataFrame.rolling` for averages and then `vectorize` for the signal (this is the big speed advantage of code over spreadsheet).... you will see when you do it.  I am sure you will have follow up questions.

Comment: @D.L   `Vectorize` has sent me down an extremely helpful rabbit hole. I will definitely get back to you will follow-up questions. Thank you!

Comment: yes, it is a big gain, especially when the processing & data is larger. It will be interesting to see your follow up questions....